# Presto - How to filter for records starting from current year using date_trunc() function?

Tags: presto

Wondering how to filter for records since beginning of current year?

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT date_id, item_id, product_name, product_price, sum(order*product_price) as revenue
FROM sales_table 
WHERE year(date_id) >= date_trunc('year', current_date)
```

There is an error on the 'year' when I executed this code.

Could someone advise? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What error are you getting? What's the type of `date_id` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct except that [`date_trunc`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_trunc) returns a date, not year number:

```
presto:tiny> SELECT date_trunc('year', current_date);
   _col0
------------
 2020-01-01
```

Assuming `date_id` is `date` data type, your query will be:

```
SELECT * FROM sales_table WHERE date_id >= date_trunc('year', current_date);
```